# Android get private maven dependencies with ssh key

Tags: maven, gradle, ssh, repository

I've made an android library, it is on a maven repository on Bitbucket.
Currently to compile the library on an android project I'm doing this:

```
maven {
        credentials {
            username BITBUCKET_USERNAME
            password BITBUCKET_PASSWORD
        }
        url ""
    }
```

I would like to use the ssh key instead, I've already generated one and add it to the bitbucket repository.

Do you have any idea how I could give the ssh key instead of username/password with gradle ?

Comment: It should work out of the box if the ssh key owner is the user running Gradle, doesn't it ?

Comment: I thought it would work like this but it's actually not. Android Studio is not able to download the aar file

Comment: Does it work if you build with a command-line ?

Comment: Not even on command line. It return a 401 ...